# Reading soi marker from jpeg header file

Tags: c, jpeg

I want to read start of image marker from JPEG header file. How to read this marker from JPEG header file in c?

Answer (score 1):

The *start of image* code is `FF` `D8`, so you need to find those bytes in the sequence, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char seq[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0xFF, 0xD8, 'S', 'O', 'I', 0x00};
    unsigned char *res = seq;

    /* We can not use strstr because seq is not a valid string */
    while ((res = memchr(res, 0xFF, sizeof seq - (res - seq)))) {
        if (*(++res) == 0xD8) {
            res++; /* + 1 to consume 0xD8 */
            break;
        }
    }
    if (res != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
SOI
```

Answer (score 0):

Any marker in a jpeg header is preceded by the start marker of `0xFF`, the soi marker is `0xD8`.
Because of this you can simply iterate through the data until you find a byte with the value `0xFF` and check if the following byte is `0xD8`. Congratulations, you have now found the soi marker.